# Slow PHP script which formats, sorts, and removes duplicates from list

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that is called by a jQuery .post which will submit a list of email addresses, perform some operations on the list (remove duplicates, sort, format, etc.), and then store each into a MySQL database.

The problem that I'm having is that it takes a really long time to perform this operation on a large list. I am testing with a list of 15,000 e-mail addresses and in 300 seconds (5 minutes), it only adds around 5,000 of the addresses.

Is there something about my code that would take a long time to process?  Here it is. I know that I'm doing a lot of formatting, but that is only because some of the e-mail addresses contain weird characters, etc.

```
// form posts
$addresses = $_POST['email_addresses'];

// cleanse and format
$addresses = trim($addresses);
$addresses = trim($addresses, "\xC2\xA0");
$addresses = str_replace(" ", "", $addresses);
$addresses = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $addresses);
$addresses = str_replace("\n", ",", $addresses);
$addresses = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $addresses); 
$addresses = strtolower($addresses);
$array_addresses = explode(",", $addresses);

// get unique values
$unique_addresses = array();
foreach($array_addresses as $key => $value) {
    if(filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
        $unique_addresses[$value] = $value;
    }
}

sort($unique_addresses);

foreach($unique_addresses as $arr) {

    if ($insert_addresses_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO email_addresses (lid, email_addresses) VALUES (?, ?)")) {

        $insert_addresses_stmt->bind_param("ss", $new_lid, $arr);

        $insert_addresses_stmt->execute();

        $insert_addresses_stmt->close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a profiler like xdebug to find out _what_ in the code is slow. But, dollars to donuts it is the _add each address to the database_ which is slowing your down.

Comment: The first section seems redundant, using just the filter should do it. Apart from that, if addresses get added at all, the bottle-neck is in the database operations. You should add the addresses in batches instead of one by one.

Comment: How are you doing the DB insert? Are you making a DB call for each address or are you batching the inserts somehow?

Comment: So, it must get past all of that formatting to the database code if it added 5000 items. Can you share the database code?

Comment: I've updated with the post with the code to insert into the database.

Comment: Wow, not only are you not sending batches, you are also preparing the same statement over and over. There's your problem.

Comment: To be a bit more helpful: Move the `prepare` statement to before the loop and see what happens. Then you can start experimenting with batch inserts.

Comment: Ok, so I moved the prepare statement outside of the loop and that helps a little bit, but not much. It allows me to add an additional 1,000 addresses in the 300 second timeframe. I will start experimenting with batch inserts. Should I use one insert statement, ie INSERT INTO email_addresses (x,y) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?),etc.? Or should I split it up more into two or three statements?

Comment: There's is a maximum length to query you can effectively send to MySQL (see max_allowed_packet), so you probably don't want to try to go all the 15000 at a time. Considering your data it's probably reasonable to batch at somewhere between 500-2000...

For smaller speed improvement also, I don't see any reason to sort the data before inserting into database. Profiling the code would indicate by how much percentage ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to comment this but cant do yet.. Anyway, pure logic gives me a clue that such a huge multi-filtered/checked/replaced post does some problems to server CPU/RAM and overloads PHP memory which I have experienced with huge queries... so lets give to it some air to spare.

You may give this (way) a shot. To do one by one (email) job - not as a 15k bunch. And await about 30 seconds for this job to complete.

```
// form posts
$add = $_POST['email_addresses']; //15.000 emails in this I suppose

//do walk in a park work first
$add = trim($add, "\xC2\xA0");

//lets get emails one by one..
$addr = explode(",", $add);
unset($add); //flush sufficient data

  {
    while (list($key,$add) = each($addr))
    {

// cleanse and format 1by1
$addresses = str_replace(' ', '', $add);
$addresses = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $addresses);
$addresses = str_replace("\n", ",", $addresses);
$addresses = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $addresses); 

//finally lower chars
$addresses = strtolower($addresses);

//check email
    if(filter_var($addresses, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
//do mysql query (first) if email already exists in your DB. if not...
-> insert this email to DB
   }


 }
}
//done
```

Of course, this "way" of doing it is not using sort() function before DB entries, since this is 1by1 insert, not a 15k bunch insert in 1 DB row (where `sort()` is essential). Guess its not necessary since we can draw data out sorted by later.